# EMACS Saving Issue

Tags: emacs

Doing some work for fun on the side and learning but i cant get passed this one section told me to create a `my_emacs_file` in `/tmp` which i did but I am doing something wrong or its not reading it please help!

I have tried to watch tutorials of this exact process of saving and still says its not working thanks for the help in advance. I have also tried to ask some people that are also in the class and they cant seem to do it either. Because when i hit submit it says this:

```
 "You don't seem to have created the /tmp/my_emacs_file with 
  emacs properly. Can you try again?"
```

Which is confusing me because when i type ls a file named "`my_emacs_file`" pops out any advice thank you again.

**Picture:**

[image]

Comment: Impossible to tell, as it is not known how the checking algorithm works. Is the file non-empty? Maybe wrong permissions? Also this is not really a question for stackoverflow, but something you should clarify by sending an e-mail to whatever person gave you the exercise.

Comment: do you know if the commands i did were done right simon? because it says type something but i dont know what it wants?

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal:

1. `cd /tmp` : changes the current directory to /tmp
2. `pwd` : making sure you are really in it
3. `emacs my_emacs_file` : and press Return (or Enter): creates `my_emacs_file` inside `/tmp`. You may see some warnings, ignore them.
4. Type anything.
5. Type `C-x` `C-s` : saves the file (you should see at the bottom `Wrote /tmp/my_emacs_file`).
6. Type `C-x` `C-c` : quits Emacs
7. `ls` : check if your newly created file is at this location.

Comment: Step 3 could be clarified to state that an empty buffer is created with a `default-directory` of ... and a buffer name of "...".

Comment: You are correct. However, I wanted to keep things "simple", so to speak, using familiar terms. :-)